# How to Stretch window?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I've a problem with my window control in WPF project. I don't find how to stretch (resize) this window or the Grid which is inner for it. I try to attach the properties HorizontalContentAlignment = "Stretch" and VerticalContentAlignment = "Stretch" consistent over the both controls, but nothing. Have you any idea what i wrong ?

That is part from my XAML:

Window

```
Title="MyWindow" AllowsTransparency="True" Background="Transparent" WindowStyle="None"

<Grid x:Name="mainGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">        
    <Border x:Name="mainBorder" Background="{DynamicResource ShellBackground}" CornerRadius="15" BorderThickness="3" Margin="0,0,10,9">

        <Grid Background="{DynamicResource BrandingBrush}">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="30" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
               ...
        </Grid>
</Grid>
```

/Window

Comment: Instead of `Auto` try `*`

Comment: are wanting to maximize the window or have the grid rows fill the window?

Comment: Yes, I have grid rows, which I must to resize respectively, too :)

Answer (score 0):

As @Shoe has correctly hinted in the comments, in order for a `Grid` to completely fill the space of its parent, at least one of its columns and rows must have a dimension set to `"*"`. From the `Grid` Class page on MSDN:

> Columns and rows that are defined within a Grid can take advantage of Star sizing to distribute remaining space proportionally. When Star is selected as the height or width of a row or column, that column or row receives a weighted proportion of the remaining available space. This is in contrast to Auto, which distributes space evenly based on the size of the content that is within a column or row.

In this example (taken from the [Grid Panel](http://wpftutorial.net/GridLayout.html) page on WPF Tutorials.net), only the `Height` will fill the complete `Height` from the parent, as it uses a `"*"` in one of the rows... the `Width` of the `Grid` will depend on the content in the first column, as it's `Width` is set to `"Auto"`:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="28" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use RowDefinition Height="*"

I hope the below does what you want:

```
<Grid x:Name="mainGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Border x:Name="mainBorder" Background="blue" CornerRadius="15" BorderThickness="3" Margin="0,0,10,9">
        <Grid Background="Red" Margin="20,20,20,20">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="30" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="123" Grid.Row="0"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="345" Grid.Row="1"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="678" Grid.Row="2"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="910" Grid.Row="3"></TextBlock>
        </Grid>
    </Border>               
</Grid>
```